# Keep my DOMDocument/DOMXpath PHP Script from Hogging Memory?

Tags: php

Made this script to crawl certain links on a forum and extract the username, post date, and post number.

It works great, the only problem is that it hogs memory and after about a half hour it slows down significantly.

Does anyone have suggestions to speed it up? I've been running a WGET on my server to start the script.

Thanks,
Nick

```
   <?
//this php script is going to download pages and tear them apart from ###

/*
Here's the process:

1. prepare url 
2. get new HTML document from the web
3. extract xpath data
4. input in mysql database
*/


$baseURL="http://www.###.com";

//end viewtopic.php?p=357850
for ($post = 325479; $post <= 357850; $post++) {

//connect to mysql
if (!mysql_connect('localhost','###','###')) echo mysql_error;
mysql_select_db('###');

//check to see if the post is already indexed
$result = mysql_query("SELECT postnumber FROM ### WHERE postnumber = '$post'");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    //echo "Already in the database." . "<br>";
    mysql_close();
    continue;
}

$url=$baseURL."/viewtopic.php?p=".$post;
//echo $url."<br>";

//get new HTML document
$html = new DOMDocument(); 
$html->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($html);

//select the page elements that you want
//I want the parent of the TD class = forumRow
$links = $xpath->query( "//td[@class='forumRow']/parent::tr" ); 

    foreach($links as $results){
        $newDom = new DOMDocument;
        $newDom->appendChild($newDom->importNode($results,true));

        $xpath = new DOMXpath ($newDom);

        //which parts of the selection do you want?
        $time_stamp = trim($xpath->query("//td[2]/table/tr/td/span")->item(0)->nodeValue);
        $user_name = trim($xpath->query("//a[@class='genmed']")->item(0)->nodeValue);
        $post_number = trim($xpath->query("//td/a/@name")->item(0)->nodeValue);

        $return[] = array(
            'time_stamp' => $time_stamp,
            'username' => $user_name,
            'post_number' => $post_number,
            );
    }

    foreach ($return as $output) {
        if (strlen($output['time_stamp']) > 0 && strlen($output['username']) > 0) 
          {
          //$timestamp = substr($output['time_stamp'],8,25);
          //echo $timestamp . "<br>";
          //$unixtimestamp = strtotime($timestamp);
          //echo $unixtimestamp;
          //echo $output['time_stamp']."<br>";
          preg_match("/[Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec]{3} \d{1,2}[,] \d{4} \d{1,2}[:]\d{2}/", $output['time_stamp'],$matches). "<br>";
          $unixtimestamp = strtotime($matches[0]);

          //YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
          $phpdate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$unixtimestamp);
          $username=$output['username'];
          $post_number=$output['post_number'];
          //echo $phpdate ." by ". $username . " #" . $post_number ;

          $result = mysql_query("SELECT postnumber FROM ### WHERE postnumber = '$post_number'");
          if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {         
            if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO ### VALUES('','$url','$username','$phpdate','$post_number')")) echo "Y";
            else echo "N";
            mysql_close();
          }
          echo "<br>";
          }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: did you already identify which parts of the code cause the increase in memory?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: (1) Why do you open a new connection to the DB *for each post*? (2) `/[Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec]{3} ...` does not (only) match what you think it does

Comment: If the problem is DOM (the whole document needs to be loaded and the tree is build, so yes, this can use some memory if the document is big. On the other site, we are talking about websites here), you should consider another XML parser, like SAX or a Pull parser like `XMLReader`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.xmlreader.php

Comment: @Gordon: How do I identify which parts of the code cause the increase in memory?

Comment: @lonesomeday: I'm using php5, "PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2" specifically.

Comment: @jensgram: I was told that opening a new connection and closing after each post might free up the memory. Not the case?

Comment: With a profiler, for instance XDebug or manually: http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php

Comment: @Castgame I think you'll be better off following @netcoder's advice on `mysql_free_result()` instead. That is, *if* the result set consumpts your memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [mysql_free_result](http://php.net/mysql_free_result). Also, the fact that you are maintaining a $return array thorough the whole script doesn't help. If you want to avoid memory issues, you should crawl a dozen records, insert them, reset $return, crawl a dozen more, insert, reset... and so on. Otherwise, the $return array gets huge, and that's probably is one of the causes (if not the cause) of your problem.

Comment: Thank you that definitely helped.